# Jquery onclick button NEXT in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, css

I need help with my form. My knowledge about jQuery is poor, this code below I found on google. I need form, and I know how to create forms in HTML5 and CSS3 use, but I dont know how to use HIDE and SHOW options in jQuery, and connect with the NEXT button.

I want to do this https://s24.postimg.org/l8ogszanp/form.png

```js
 var step=1;
  $("#next").on("click")
  function{
    $("step"+step).hide();
    step+=1
    $("steo"+step).show(); 
  }
```

```css
.step1 {
    display: block;
    background-color: silver;
  }

  .step2 {
    display: none;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .step3 {
    display: none;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .step4 {
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .step5 {
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="step1">
    <p>Content 1</p>
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <div class="step2">
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <div class="step3">
    <p>Content 3</p>
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <div class="step4">
    <p>Content 4</p>
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <div class="step5">
    <p>Content 5</p>
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you are looking for someone to write this code for you?

Comment: For one, `$("#next").on("click") function {` should be `$("#next").on("click, function() {   // CODE HERE });`

Comment: Let's start off with you can't have duplicate IDs in your document, you didn't include jQuery in your example, and you have a typo in `$("steo"+step)`. Also you left out the period in both `$("step"` lines (should be `$(".step"`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a dot.

```
  function{
$(".step"+step).hide();
step+=1
$(".step"+step).show(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need that many "next" buttons. For ID's you should only ever have one on the page, and in this instance, it can be reused for each item.
2. You need to add the class indicator in the step calls `$(".step" + step)...`
3. The `.on('click', function()...` code was improperly formed.

The snippet below should help push you into the right direction for moving forward.

```js
var step = 1;
$("#next").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".step" + step).hide();
  step+= 1;
  $(".step" + step).show();
});
```

```css
.step1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: silver;
}

.step2 {
  display: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.step3 {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
}

.step4 {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.step5 {
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="step1">
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step2">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step3">
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step4">
      <p>Content 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step5">
      <p>Content 5</p>
    </div>
    <button id="next">NEXT</button>
  </form>
</div>
```